# Separate every word in a camelCase string except certain white listed ones

Tags: regex

I've got some code splitting a camelCase string into a sentence where each word is separated by a space. That I've managed to do using the regex  `(?=\p{Lu})`, but I now also want to exclude a set of camelCase substrings which should kept as they are.

For example, if the words I'm trying to preserve are `Class` and `MultiWordClass`, I would want:

```
containsAClassName -> contains A Class Name
containsAMultiWordClassName -> contains A MultiWordClass Name
        (the positions not to match) -->       ^   ^
```

My question is how I can extend that expression to not match positions inside the words I want to preserve. Or possibly, if that is not possible, how I can use a combination of regex and Java to do it. I've been trying for some time now, and can't come up with a solution that works. I'm using Java's regex-engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a substitution regular expression that you can use for this purpose:

```perl
s/([[:alpha:]](?=[[:upper:]])|MultiWordClass|OtherMultiWordClass)/$1 /g
```

I tried that with Perl, I'm not sure if Java's regexps are fully compatible with Perl's -- if not, it should be easily adaptable.

Comment: I modified the pattern somewhat `(MultiWordClass|Class|\p{L})(?=\p{Lu}|$)`, to ensure partial matches of recognized words aren't matched. (L=unicode letter, Lu=unicode letter uppercase)

Comment: Right, I didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

MultiWordClasses are tricky, since you don't want to split between the WordClasses part either. Instead, I'd suggest a different strategy than your regex: tokenize your string and convert individual tokens to their spaced out versions before combining the results. That makes it much easier to skip whitelisted tokens.

You can consider each whitelisted word a potential token, and each substring that doesn't contain whitelisted words a token. To create the tokens, just scan along the string until you find one of your whitelisted words; then take everything before that, append it to the tokens list, then append the whitelisted word; then repeat the process, until you get to the end of the string.

Comment: Actually, in the singe word case, no change is needed - my current pattern already parses it as expected. It is the separators between Multi/Word and Word/Class that I want to *not* match.

Comment: Right, yeah. Edited the answer to reflect that.